# Shared service with BehaviorSubject not emitting correct value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I am trying to implement a shared service for managing Roles on my app, with an `Observable` so that, from other components, you can either change the current role and be notified when it changes.  The problem I have is that when I publish a new value through the service, the components that subscribe to the observable always recieve the same value (the initial one).  Then, I never receive the new role number and I can't update the component state.

Apparently 
I have the following set of components:

- **RolesService**: The shared Service, which manages role change, gets the available roles from the user token, manages persistence of the current role for the logged in user. It uses localStorage to persist the role index. It receives changes
- **HeaderComponent**: This is an example of a component receiving changes for the role change, because it needs to update the title of the user. It subscribes to the observable and changes the title accordingly
- **EscullRolComponent**: And this is an example of a component that changes the role the user is currently using (by action of the user, of course). It has some buttons and sends to the service the new index.

Here is the relevant code for this issue:

```js
// RolesService file
@Injectable()
export class RolesService {

  private _currentRole: BehaviorSubject<Rol> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  currentRole = this._currentRole.asObservable();

  private get currentIndex(): number {
    const ras = localStorage.getItem('current_role');
    // console.log("Guardat aixo: ", ras);
    if (ras === '' || ras === null || ras === 'NaN' || ras === '-1' || parseInt(ras, 10) === NaN) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return parseInt(ras, 10);
    }
  }

  private set currentIndex(val) {
    localStorage.setItem('current_role', val.toString());
  }

  currentToken: NbAuthJWTToken;

  constructor(private authService: NbAuthService,
              private http: HttpClient) {
    // console.log(this.currentRole);
    this.authService.getToken().subscribe((token: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
      if (token.isValid()) {
        this.currentToken = token;
        console.log("Executing token change");
        this.setRolActual(0);
      }
    });
  }

  protected publishCurrentRol(i: number): void {
    console.log("Publishing rol id: ", i); // LOG 1
    this._currentRole.next(this.getUserRoles()[i]);
  }

  setRolActual(i: number) {
    this.publishCurrentRol(i);
    this.currentIndex = i;
  }
}
```

The following is the component the user has to change the role, and that calls the service with the new role.

```js
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'escull-rol.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['escull-rol.component.scss'],
})
export class EscullRolComponent {
  rols: Array<Rol> = [];
  actual: number;


  constructor(  private rolesService: RolesService,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router,
                private location: Location ) {
    this.rols = this.rolesService.getUserRoles();
    this.actual = this.rolesService.getRolActualIndex();
  }

  buttonRolClicked(index: number) {
    this.rolesService.setRolActual(index);
    this.router.navigate(['inici']);
    // console.log('Boto del rol ' +  index + ' clicat');
  }
}
```

And here the header, which changes its state depending on the role:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-header',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input() position = 'normal';

  user: any = {};
  picture: string;
  client: stream.Client;

  logoPath = '';
  logoEra = '';

  rol: string;
  ids: Array<string>;

  constructor(private sidebarService: NbSidebarService,
              /* ... more injections .. */
              private imatgesService: ImatgesService,
              private notificacionsService: NotificacionsService) {

    this.logoEra = 'assets/images/logoEra.png';

    this.authService.onTokenChange()
    .subscribe((token: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
      if (token.isValid()) {
        if (token.getValue()) {
                        this.user = token.getPayload(); // Posem les dades del token a l'objecte user
                        // console.log('token changed, changing user in header', token);
                      }
                    }
                  }, error => {
      console.error('Error en carregar el token en el header');
      throw error;
    });

    this.rolesService.currentRole.subscribe((rol: Rol) => {
      // This subscription here should receive the change from the service
      if(rol) {
        console.log("Changing rol on header to ", rol.getIndex()); // LOG 2
        this.rol = rol.getTitle();
        this.ids = rol.getRolIDs();
      }

    });

    this.imatgesService.getProfileImagePath().subscribe((path: string) => {
      this.picture = path;
    }, (err) => {
      this.picture = '';
    });

  }
}
```

The behaviour that I'm seeing is, the EscullRol component calling the `setRolActual(id)` method with the new id, and then the service calling its internal method `publishCurrentRole(id)` with the same `id`, so at *LOG 1* I can see the expected outoput.  But then immediately next I can see the output form *LOG 2* at the Header Component with the wrong `id`, which is always the number that we had initially saved at the `localStorage` when the app started up.

I don't really know if the issue is with how I use the observables, with the service-component communication model or with how components and observables are initailsed and treated in angular.

Comment: I might be this line:  currentRole = this._currentRole.asObservable(); Could it be keeping the subject as it was created? Another Idea could be to test what happens if you change the BehaviorSubject to and ordinary Subject

Comment: If you try to use Subject instead BehaviorSubject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few thing to try

First make your service as a singleton using

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
```

***Improvement***
Also, make sure that the service is not provided on child modules, as that would create their own instance and it wouldn't be a *singleton* anymore.  If there are more than one instance of the service, the Subject-Observer pattern will not work across all the app.

Then this code

```
currentRole = this._currentRole.asObservable();
```

You should create a function to return the data not defined as an variable like

```
   getCurrentRole() {
     return this._currentRole.asObservable();
   }
```